# Are Nikon focus screens cross compatible?

Tags: nikon, repair, focusing-screen

I was cleaning the mirror on my D3200 today and in the process somehow scratched the exposed side of the focus screen. Oops. Now instead of dust specks I have these gently curving permanent streaks on the viewfinder. It doesn't affect the pictures at all but it's annoying to look at.

[Replacements aren't crazy priced](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/519949-REG/Nikon_25371_Type_B_BriteView_Clear.html), thankfully, and the process of switching it out looks very simple and requires only soft tweezers.

While looking for this part I came upon other focus screens for Nikon, like Type F, C, M, E to name a [few](http://mir.com.my/rb/photography/hardwares/classics/nikonf4/screens/index.htm). Out of curiosity, would these also fit my camera?

Answer (score 2):

My experience with Nikon bodies is that each body takes a slightly different shaped focusing screen.  Even the second link in your question points out that there are different screens for the F4 and F5 bodies.

You'll need to make sure you're getting a screen specifically for your model of camera.